# What if my subclasses have different methods too?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a question about polymorphism in Java. I have a abstract base class `Shape` and two derived classes `Rectangle` and `Circle`. I know that I can call overridden methods in `Circle` and `Rectangle` class with a `Shape` class reference but what if I have a method that `Shape` class doesn't have but `Circle` class has. How can I use polymorphism in this situation?

Comment: `What if I have a method that Shape class doesn't have but Circle class has.` - you can not call this method directly using the reference of `Shape`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use polymorphism in this situation. The very idea of polymorphism is that you can use an object in a specified way irrespective of its actual shape (specific object type). By requiring access to a method that is unique to (literally) a specific shape, you must forego polymorphism.

(*The above argument would not apply if `Circle` actually had subclasses, in which case you could polymorphically call these methods, but this is just moving the argument somewhere else*.)

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time. The answer is that you need to cast your Shape to a Circle to access the method

```
Shape s = ...;
if (s instanceof Circle) {
  ((Circle)s).foo(); //method only on Circle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store a Circle in a Shape instance, you can invoke Circle methods on s by casting s to Circle:

```
Shape s = new Circle();
...
if ( s.instanceof(Circle) ) {
   ((Circle)s).circleMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the casting solution suggested by other answers, if you think all subclasses of `Shape` should provide that method but you can't/don't want to implement it on `Shape`, you can declare the method as abstract and implement the method in `Circle` and `Rectangle`.

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void foo();
}


public class Circle extends Shape {
    public void foo() {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

then you can do:

```
Shape s = new Circle();
s.foo();
```

Comment: But what if Circle class has another method that Shape class doenst has?

Comment: Then you can add an abstract method declaration with the same signature to the `Shape` class if it makes sense for a `Shape` instance to have that method in the context of your program. If the method isn't fit for a `Shape` to have you can use the casting approach provided in other answers. Whether it "makes sense" or not is most likely a design decision specific to your problem domain rather than an implementation decision.